# Metaclass pass classname as parameter

Tags: python, python-2.7, metaclass

I have metaclass like:

```
class Metaclass(type):
    def __new__(self, name, bases, attrs):

        for k, v in attrs.iteritems():
            if isinstance(v, types.FunctionType):
               attrs[k] = self.decorator(v)
        return super(MetaClass, self).__new__(self, name, bases, attrs)

    @classmethod
    def decorator(cls, func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print(func.__name__)
```

But I can't get `func.__class__.__name__` it prints metaclass. I want to get name of class of `func.__name__`.
Apparently It's not possible it python 2.7(?)
Can I pass classname as a parameter? for method who calls this decorator? 
i.e. if `testmethod` calls metaclass decorator and passes `Testclass` as parameter. So if I know `func.__name__` is from specific class do specific things.

Comment: `func.__class__` isn't the class where the function was defined; it's `types.FunctionType`, the class of the function object itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to return the wrapper from the decorator. It should be:

```
class Metaclass(type):
    def __new__(self, name, bases, attrs):

        for k, v in attrs.iteritems():
            if isinstance(v, types.FunctionType):
               attrs[k] = self.decorator(v)
        return super(Metaclass, self).__new__(self, name, bases, attrs)

    @classmethod
    def decorator(cls, func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print(func.__name__)
        return wrapper
```

You can now use the metaclass:

```
>>> class TestClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = Metaclass
    def foo(self):
        return "bar"

>>> t = TestClass()
>>> x = t.foo()
foo
>>> print x
None
```

The method has been correctly be replaced by the wrapper.

---

In you previous (now deleted) question you asked for *print "this method is from Testclass"*. You can simply pass the class name to the decorator:

```
class Metaclass(type):
    def __new__(self, name, bases, attrs):

        for k, v in attrs.iteritems():
            if isinstance(v, types.FunctionType):
               attrs[k] = self.decorator(v, name)
        return super(Metaclass, self).__new__(self, name, bases, attrs)

    @classmethod
    def decorator(cls, func, name):
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print "%s defined in %s called from %s instance" % (func.__name__,
                name, self.__class__.__name__)
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
```

You obtain now:

```
>>> class TestClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = Metaclass
    def foo(self):
        return "bar"


>>> t = TestClass()
>>> x = t.foo()
foo defined in TestClass called from TestClass instance
>>> print x
bar
```

Comment: `name` does give me name of class from which method is from. i.e. if `test1` method is in `TestChild1` class, and I call `test1` as ``` testChild1Class = TestChild1() testChild1Class.nest1() ``` I get `name` as TestChild1. But if I call method `test1parent` in parent class like `testChild1Class.test1parent()` I get parent class in name. Can I get child class name here?

Comment: `func.__name__` is  by construction the name of the class that declared the method. If you want the class name of current object, just use `self.__class__.__name__` as shown in edited post